# Best way to keep track of subdomain for guests

Tags: php, subdomain

I am trying to create subdomains for users as each has their own "website". (user.domain.com) This is all "virtual" as all the files, controllers, folders, etc are the same. Everything is dynamically created. I think I've got all the DNS, mod_rewrite, htaccess, etc stuff down, but I've got another problem.

The problem is when a guest (non-user) visits a user's website (user.domain.com). An example to illustrate this:

1. Guest types url with subdomain (btw, I'm using php) and controller dynamically loads up the user website based on the subdomain.
2. Guest clicks on a link on the page and gets a new page from server. Problem is that the new page doesn't have the subdomain anymore as all the links are the same. Only the content is different and dynamically loaded.

So the question is, How do I keep track of which subdomain the guest is on? Since the client is a guest and not a logged in user, I can't look at the logged in user's information.

I am just interested in ideas of what the best implementation would be. Should I keep some variable in the session and keep checking that on each page? Should I pass a POST/GET variable with each link and then have the controller read that?

Comment: Save his subdomain on the session. And if he changes subdomain, re-save it on the session.

Comment: Cant you pre-pend all links with the subdomain of the first page the guest visited? You could hold this in a session?

Comment: In your 2nd point you are saying that new page does not have subdomain anymore. Should it have? or you should at least have something to hold on to that or in your database you would know which type of content is for which subdomain and then send that to your view as well to keep track of it.

Comment: You can md5 domain with a user specific secret salt that you have in database and then store it in session that way you dont have to worry about other people changing session value and getting content of another domain etc. Maybe you dont need that much secrecy but just a thought

Comment: Interesting. So Hanlet seems to support my first idea (save subdomain as variable in session) and diagonal seems to support my second idea (passing POST/GET variable was me trying to say pre-pending all links with subdomain info). Does it matter which is better?

Comment: Farrukh, to answer, yes it does matter. My question was essentially, "what is the best way to "hold on" (to use your words) to the subdomain info". Also, that md5 idea is a good one. Indeed, I don't want people just getting other subdomains all willy nilly.

Comment: Surely you do both, save the domain in the session and pre-pend all  links with it so the user always goes to the domain from the session, just keep updating the session with the current domain on each page load so it is always up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']
```

This will give you the domain, just keep it in the session.